# ogg to mp3 using NAudio MFT

Tags: c#-4.0, mp3, naudio, ogg, oggvorbis

Here, I am having a problem while converting ogg file to mp3 format. Reading ogg file is done successfully but while encoding it is throwing exception like,"Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D3E85". Presently I am working on windows server 2012(64 bit).

```
public byte[] DecodeOGG(byte[] data,string trgtfilename,int bitrate)
{      
   byte[] dt = null;
   NVorbis.NAudioSupport.VorbisWaveReader vr = null;
   using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
   {
      ms.Position = 0;
      vr = new NVorbis.NAudioSupport.VorbisWaveReader(ms);
   }                        
   var samp = new SampleChannel(vr);
   var ws = new SampleToWaveProvider16(samp);
   MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(ws, trgtfilename, bitrate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `MediaFoundationInterop.Startup()` somewhere in your application. NAudio may be updated in the future to call this automatically.